# html generation using php

Tags: php, html

i have a simple form with 3 inputs

```
<form method="post" action="action.php">
   <input type="text" id="a">
   <input type="text" id="b">
   <input type="text" id="c">
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
 </form>
```

I want to send data from inputs to textareas with similar ids in generated html page which is send to my email. Generated html page should look this way:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>action</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/zenorocha/clipboard.js/master/dist/clipboard.min.js"></script>  
    </head>
    <body>
    <script>
new Clipboard('.btn-clipboard'); 
</script>
 <textarea id="a">1</textarea>
<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#a">Copy</button>
 <textarea id="b">2</textarea>
<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#b">Copy</button>
 <textarea id="c">3</textarea>
<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#c">Copy</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please help me to realize this

Comment: Have you tried anything? If you're having trouble, giving your inputs name attributes will be necessary to get anything from $_POST in PHP.

Comment: Start here [The PHP how to write a form Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/tutorial.forms.php)

Answer (score 0):

In action.php:

```
<textarea id="a"><?=$_POST["a"]?></textarea>
<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#a">Copy</button>
<textarea id="b"><?=$_POST["b"]?></textarea>
<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#b">Copy</button>
<textarea id="c"><?=$_POST["c"]?></textarea>
<button class="btn-clipboard" data-clipboard-target="#c">Copy</button>
```